# MySQL Error 1054: Unknown Column 'hotels.postal_code' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, union, mysql-error-1054, mysql-error-1052

I'm not too sure why but my codes can't seem to work. Its either I get Error 1052 or 1054. 
Here are my codes. Please Help.

```
SELECT

    hotels.postal_code AS ' Hotel Postal Code',
    name AS 'Hotel Name',
    latitude AS 'Latitude',
    longitude AS 'Longitude',
    address AS 'Hotel Address',
    hyperlink AS 'Hotel Hyperlink',
    hotels.district AS 'Hotel District',
    'hotel' AS type

FROM
    hotels

        join
    hotel_sales ON hotels.postal_code = hotel_sales.sales_id
        join
    postal_code_location ON hotels.district = postal_code_location.district 

UNION SELECT 

    malls.postal_code AS ' Mall Postal Code',
    name AS 'Mall Name',
    latitude AS 'Latitude',
    longitude AS 'Longitude',
    address AS 'Mall Address',
    hyperlink AS 'Mall Hyperlink',
    malls.district AS 'Mall District',
    'mall' AS type
FROM
malls

        join
    hotel_sales ON hotels.postal_code = hotel_sales.sales_id
        join
    postal_code_location ON hotels.district = postal_code_location.district
```

Comment: Can you share the DDLs of your tables?

Comment: `ON hotels.postal_code = hotel_sales.sales_id` seems to be wrong. Sounds to me like it should be `ON hotels.hotel_id = hotel_sales.hotel_id`?

Comment: In your 2nd select, you are joining on `hotels.postal_code`, but `hotels` is not being used in that query.  You are selecting from `malls`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes it does have it.

Comment: @user3293517: The schemas.  What columns the table has.

Comment: @KayNelson The postal_code field is my primary key for hotels.

Comment: The hotels table has 
postal_code (PK)
name
latitude
longitude
address
hyperlink
district
region

Comment: And for malls? Anyway, a postal_code as primary key for hotels? I hope you never have hotels close to one another...

Comment: Ok, so only one hotel can be in a postcode?

Comment: @oerkelens Yeah same for malls, postal code is the primary key.

Comment: @Kay Nelson Yeah, the postal codes are unique to each hotel.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think in MALLS you call it HOTELS.POSTAL_CODE, do you? I think Rocket Hazmat gave you the correct answer already ;)

Comment: My malls table has
postal_code (PK)
name
latitude
longitude
address 
hyperlink
district

Comment: Good, now have another look at your SECOND select ;) And please, please, _DO_ reconsider your PK. This is asking for problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
FROM
malls

        join
    hotel_sales ON hotels.postal_code = hotel_sales.sales_id
```

AS

```
FROM
malls

        join
    hotel_sales ON malls.postal_code = hotel_sales.sales_id
```

Joining `MALLS` and `HOTEL_SALES` with right column...

So the final Query would be..

```
SELECT

    hotels.postal_code AS ' Hotel Postal Code',
    name AS 'Hotel Name',
    latitude AS 'Latitude',
    longitude AS 'Longitude',
    address AS 'Hotel Address',
    hyperlink AS 'Hotel Hyperlink',
    hotels.district AS 'Hotel District',
    'hotel' AS type

FROM
    hotels

        join
    hotel_sales ON hotels.postal_code = hotel_sales.sales_id
        join
    postal_code_location ON hotels.district = postal_code_location.district 

UNION SELECT 

    malls.postal_code AS ' Mall Postal Code',
    name AS 'Mall Name',
    latitude AS 'Latitude',
    longitude AS 'Longitude',
    address AS 'Mall Address',
    hyperlink AS 'Mall Hyperlink',
    malls.district AS 'Mall District',
    'mall' AS type
FROM
malls

        join
    hotel_sales ON malls.postal_code = hotel_sales.sales_id
        join
    postal_code_location ON hotels.district = postal_code_location.district
```

Comment: You really want to edit `hotels.district` as well, before we get "doesn't work" again :)

Answer (score 1):

This error is about

> Disambiguate column_id in your Query

It should be something like this

```
SELECT
    hotels.postal_code AS ' Hotel Postal Code',
    hotels.name AS 'Hotel Name',
    hotels.latitude AS 'Latitude',
....
```